# How can I add a missing PyQt5 modules on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, raspbian

I am using PyQt5 version 5.7, python 3.5.3 and raspbian. My problem is that in my code some modules of PyQt5 get recognized and produce no error and some do.

The error I get: *ImportError: cannot import name 'QMultimedia'*

So why does QtCore/Widgets/Gui get reconized but not QMultimedia? Do I need to install some extra packages? Do I need to reinstall and do something special? This might be a trivial question but please help me.

Note: I also tried: `from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia`

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QMultimedia
from PyQt5 import QCameraInfo
from PyQt5 import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5 import QMediaObject
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class Camera():
    def iniCamera():
        cam = QCamera()
        caminfo = QCameraInfo(cam)
        print (caminfo.description)

        if caminfo.isNull() != True:
           cam = QCamera(caminfo.deviceName())
           print (caminfo.description)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    iniCamera()
```

Comment: Change `QMultimedia` to `QtMultimedia`, is typo?

Comment: already tried that

Comment: I understand that I have tried but put the correct name, do not confuse us anymore.!!!

Comment: Did that work: `from PyQt5 import QCameraInfo
from PyQt5 import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5 import QMediaObject`?, These imports are incorrect.

Comment: How have you installed pyqt5?

Comment: Nope, those also dont work. I also dont find those in the directory for PyQt5. Only QtCore and such. I installed pyqt5 with _sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev pyqt5-dev-tools_

Comment: Then delete those things from your code or change to `from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *`

Comment: If it does not come in the package you installed, then download the source code and compile it manually.

Comment: 'from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *' produces error _ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QMultimedia'_

Comment: That is obvious, I have commented that you have to download it from the official website of PyQt5 and compile it manually, if you are a beginner it will be a bit tedious to learn how to do that, good luck.

Comment: yeah well i guess i have to pull through this. Anyway thanks for the fast answers :)

Comment: So i am in the process of installing pyqt5 and i ran into something that chaught my eye. `This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.7 (licensed under the GNU General Public
License) for Python 2.7.13 on linux2.` Why is this for Python2.7.13? I never had the chance to say that i want it for python3

Comment: Execute `python3 configure.py`

Comment: @Xenoshell. There's no need to use pip or try to compile pyqt5 yourself. Please see my answer for a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the Raspbian `pyqt5-dev` and `pyqt5-dev-tools` packages, this will only provide the core PyQt5 modules like `QtCore`, `QtGui`, `QtWidgets`, etc. For other modules like `QtMultimedia`, you must install separate packages.

If you go to the [Raspbian Connect Package List](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages-list), and look in the [Python Packages](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages-list/item/87-raspbian-python) section, you will find the following extra packages:

- python3-pyqt5.qsci
- python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia
- python3-pyqt5.qtopengl
- python3-pyqt5.qtpositioning
- python3-pyqt5.qtquick
- python3-pyqt5.qtsensors
- python3-pyqt5.qtserialport
- python3-pyqt5.qtsql
- python3-pyqt5.qtsvg
- python3-pyqt5.qtwebchannel
- python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit
- python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets
- python3-pyqt5.qtx11extras
- python3-pyqt5.qtxmlpatterns

So just use `apt-get` to install whatever else you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check your site-packages folder to see if this package actually exists.

If you are working behind a **virtualenv** (which you should), make sure it's activated. Using **`pip3 freeze`**, see if PyQt5 is correctly installed.

Then, install a pylint extension, this can help you in future missing packages and other stuff.

Comment: i actually was never able to install pyqt5 with pip3. I installed a pyqt5-installer with pip3 but never figured out how to use it so i chose to use _sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev pyqt5-dev-tools_

Comment: when i use pip3 install pyqt5. Errormessage is `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt5` even with python3.5.3

Comment: The libraries that use pip do not take into account the hardware, that is to say the processor, so they will fail for architectures of certain particular way like the ARM in the case of Raspberry Pi causing those problems, for that reason it is not suitable to use pip for install PyQt in raspberry.